# Visual C++ - Cannot call derived class functions

Tags: visual-c++, inheritance, polymorphism, derived-class

// I have a base class in the monopoly game I am making called Square. One of the derived classes from this is called freeParking. The freeParking class has a function called playSquare, I am trying to call this function, however the playSquare function call in main is giving me errors. Here is the code I am trying to use:

//the base square class

```
#pragma once
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Square
{
public:
    Square(string d);
    string displayName();
private:
    string squareName;

};
```

// The freeParking class that inherits from the Square class

```
#pragma once
#include "Square.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>

class freeParking : public Square
{
public:
freeParking(string a);
void playSquare(Player *player, Player *otherPlayer);


private:

};
```

//The freeParking playSquare function

```
#include "FreeParking.h"

using namespace std;

freeParking::freeParking(string a)
    :Square(a)
{

}

void freeParking::playSquare(Player *player, Player *otherPlayer)
{
    cout << "Player " << player->returnPlayerPiece() << " lands on free parking" << endl;
    cout << "Player " << player->returnPlayerPiece() << " is resting" << endl;
}
```

//Calling the playSquare function in main

```
vector <Square> squaresVector;
Square* square = new freeParking(squares[readCount]);
squaresVector.push_back(*square);

int a = 0;
for (vector<Square>::iterator it = squaresVector.begin(); it <squaresVector.end(); it++)
    {
        squaresVector[a]->playSquare(Player *p1, Player *p2);
            a++;
    }
```

//Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You have not made `playSquare` part of the `Square` interface. It seems like you want `playSquare` to be specific to the kind of square, but you also want to be able to call it on a `Square*` without knowing the type of `Square`. To do this, make `playSquare` a virtual method.

```
class Square {
    string squareName;

public:
    Square(string d);
    string displayName();
    virtual void playSquare(Player* p1, Player* p2) = 0; 
    ...
};
```

Add `virtual` to the front of `playSquare`'s declaration in the derived class. This is a pure virtual function, which means it is not defined in the base class, but must be defined in any derived class that is actually instantiated. If you don't like this restriction, replace `= 0` with `{}` to give it an empty default definition. My guess is that you'll want to require a definition for each derived class, given the context of a game board.

**Edit**

You cannot use `std::vector` to store polymorphic objects (objects with virtual functions). A vector will only allocate memory for the type of its template parameter, `Square` in this case. Any data relating to a derived class will get cut off. You can work around this by using a `std::vector<Square*>` instead. Since the object is no longer stored in the vector, we no longer have this problem.

On a related note, you can't copy a `Square` object without knowing what kind of `Square` it is, since the `Square` copy constructor has no idea how to handle the `freeParking` parts of an object. Your `push_back` operation attempts to do just this.

I also notice that you're using two loop counters for no particular reason. Get rid of `a`, since the iterators you've already defined allow you to access each element of the vector.

```
for(vector<Square*>::iterator it = squaresVector.begin(); it != squaresVector.end(); ++it) {
    (*it)->playSquare(p1, p2); //p1 and p2 are of type Player*
}
```

I doubt you meant to declare the arguments of `playSquare` as you're passing them, either.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, it now works. However if I store the squares in arrays, it then call the appropriate function for the correct derived class. However, when calling this from the vector defined in my original post, it calls the base class playSquare function (which i never want to call) any further advice?

Comment: I edited my answer to include that and a couple other bugs I found on closer inspection.